# function field of an integral scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is an integral scheme, and let $\eta \in X$ be its generic point. Then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is a field, called the function field of $X$ and denoted $K(X)$.

Why is $K(X)$ called a function field? In what sense (if any) are its elements functions? Is there some conceptual connection between regular functions (on a variety) and $K(X)$?

I'm asking because the name is quite suggestive, but it doesn't seem to follow directly from the definition that $K(X)$ is a field of "functions".

Comment: Very related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function

Answer (score 11):

Yes, all elements of $K(X)$ are functions, but there is a *caveat*:

**Caveat : the functions are not defined everywhere**
The field $K(X)$ is simply the union   of all $\mathcal O(U)$ with $U\subset X$ open, where one identifies $f\in \mathcal O(U)$ with $f|V\in \mathcal O(V)$ whenever $U\supset V$.
So I cheated a bit when I said that rational functions are functions: they are equivalence classes of functions.
But if you are an honest person, you can get along without cheating: in every equivalence class of such pairs $(U,f)$ there is one pair with $U$ maximal and by considering only such maximal pairs you may consider that $K(X)\subset \bigcup _{U \:\text {open}}\mathcal O(U)$ .
So, yes, $K(X)$ consists of regular functions, but these functions are not defined everywhere.
Shafarevich has made the interesting observation that this is a feature which distinguishes algebraic geometry from other geometric theories like topology or differential geometry.

Comment: OK, I reread the definition of the structure sheaf of an affine scheme from Hartshorne and it makes sense because the rings $\mathcal{O}(U)$ are defined explicitly as rings of functions. I think I was a bit confused because I have mainly been following Goertz&Wedhorn, who define the sheaf on principal open sets (as localizations of the coordinate ring) and then use sheaf properties to extend to arbitrary open sets. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Balerion, you are welcome!

Comment: Also, you are right that the elements of $\mathcal O(U)$ are functions, but with a strange codomain: I should have emphasized that aspect.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, one thing that is very confusing when first reading about the structure sheaf (aka regular functions) is that when a scheme isn't of finite type over an algebraically closed field (say $\mbox{Spec}(R)$ for any ring $R$), then the elements of $R$ don't appear to be functions. For example, the global sections of the structure sheaf of $\mbox{Spec}(k[x])$ are "obviously" functions because they're polynomials, but on the other hand elements of $\mbox{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$ aren't "obviously" functions on the corresponding spectrum.

Comment: I think this leads to a lot of confusion with the function field. That's my two cents :). +1 for a great answer!

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, what do you mean by ''the elements of $\mathcal{O}(U)$ are functions, but with a strange codomain''? Isn't the codomain just $\mathbb{A}^1$, i.e. $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\operatorname{Hom}(U,\mathbb{A}^1)$?

Comment: Dear @jeffrey, yes it is true that elements of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ corespond to morphisms $U\to \mathbb A^1$. What I meant is that an element $f\in \mathcal O_X(U)$ can be seen as a function whose value at $x\in U$ is $f(x)\in \kappa(x)$, so that the codomain of $f$ is the union of all residue fields $\kappa(x)$. This is in contrast with classical algebraic geometry over $\mathbb C$, where functions on $U$ have all their values in the same field $\mathbb C$. This is because in a complex variety all closed points (the only ones considered classically) have residue field $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, thank you. I am a little confused: Do I understand correctly, that the scheme morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(x))\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(U))$ correspond exactly to the elements of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(U))$ where the unique point in $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(x))$ is sent to the corresponding $f\in \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(U))$?

Comment: Dear @jeffrey: A function $s\in \mathcal O_X(U)$ gives what you write but in my opinion this complicates things. Just refer to the **definition** of $s\in \mathcal O_X(U)$ in Hartshorne. It is given as a map $s:U\to \sqcup _{\mathfrak p\in U} A_\mathfrak p$ on page 70. This makes it visibly clear that $s$ has a strange codomain, *viz* a disjoint union of local rings. (After that you take residue fields in order to be closer to the classical point of view of seeing $\mathcal O_x(U)$ as functions)

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, thank you. I am still confused: For an integral (say affine) scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $U$ an open subscheme, one has $$ \mathcal{O}_X(U) \overset{(*)}{=} \bigcap_{p\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,p}= \bigcap_{p\in U} A_p$$ and I thought this does not hold for non-reduced schemes. Sorry, I am very confused: The definition of Hartshorne is via union and $(*)$ is about intersection. How does this relate?

Comment: Dear @jeffrey, (*) doesn't even make sense for reducible schemes (the local rings are then not contained in a common  field or ring) and should not be used in foundational questions. I think we should end this long string of comments now. You are welcome to ask your remaining questions in a new post, which would attract and interest more users than just we two (especially since this is a rather old answer!).

Answer (score 4):

This might be kind of low-brow comparing to the other answer. Let us consider the simplest case first. Let $X=Spec A$, where $A=k[x]$. Then all the points in $X$ are given by the prime ideals of $A$, and since $A$ is a PID they are all generated by polynomials. Now the generic point corresponds to the minimal prime ideal of $A$, which is $\langle 0\rangle$ since $A$ is an integral domain. Therefore we have 
$$
\mathcal{O}_{X,0}\cong A_{0}=k(x)
$$

Now we let $Y=Spec B$, where $B=k[x_{1}\cdots x_{n}]/I$ and $I$ is prime. Then the minimal prime ideal in $B$ is again given by $0$ as an equivalence class in the quotient ring. And similarly localization gives you the functional field on $Y$ to be the fractional field of $B$. If you think $Y$ as a complex algebraic variety, then this is the quotient field of the ring of regular functions.

So coming from an affine variety, to me the functional field can be thought as some kind of "fractional field", and the notation $K(X)$ is justified in this regard. I learned this perspective by reading Mumford's [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=-4NAJvOW3A8C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). If you found any mistake, please point out to let me know.